# How to disable a react component (or onClick itself) with onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have seen similar questions but none of the answers are working in my case and I hope someone will be able to tell me why.

My ReactApp renders 3 card components that flip when clicked on. The cards are populated with data from an object array and is rendered with a map function (added info in case it has an impact). Here is parent component.

```
import React from 'react'
import FlipCard from './FlipCard'

const cards = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'NOPE',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: '!!WINNER!!',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'NOPE',
    },
]

const shuffleCards = array => {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
        const temp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = temp
    }
    return array
}
shuffleCards(cards)

console.log(cards)

const CardGameUI = () => {
    shuffleCards(cards)

    return (
        <div className="cards-ui">
            {cards.map(card => (
                <FlipCard key={card.id} text={card.text} value={card.id} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardGameUI
```

When one of the cards are flipped, I need the onClick for the other cards to be disabled. I tried using state and a conditional in my onClick event but it has no effect. The according to the console.log, the state of the play boolean is changed and if I manually change the conditional in the onCLick event check if play is true, then it works perfectly fine. I am clearly missing something because it seems as though the conditional is working and the state is changing.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactCardFlip from 'react-card-flip'
import FrontComponent from './FrontComponent'
import BackComponent from './BackComponent'

const FlipCard = ({ text, value }) => {
    const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = useState(false)
    const [activeCard, setActiveCard] = useState(2)
    const [play, setPlay] = useState(false)
    console.log(play.valueOf())

    function handleFlip() {
        setPlay(true)
        setIsFlipped(!isFlipped)
        console.log(isFlipped)
        setActiveCard(value)
        console.log(value)
    }

    if (activeCard !== 2) {
        console.log('Play again?')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
                <FrontComponent onClick={!play ? handleFlip : null} />

                <BackComponent text={text} value={value} />
            </ReactCardFlip>
        </>
    )
}

export default FlipCard
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the `onClick` event and the `flip` state on the parent instead of inside the card.

An high-level overview will be:

```
const CardGameUI = () => {
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState({});
  const hasFlipped = Object.values(flipped).includes(true);

  const handleFlip = id => () => setFlipped(flipped => ({
    ...flipped,
    [id]: true // can be changed to toggle in case you need it in the future
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map(({ id, text }) => (
        <FlipCard
          key={id}
          text={text}
          value={id}
          onFlip={handleFlip(id)}
          flipped={flipped[id]}
          disabled={hasFlipped}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

const FlipCard = ({ text, value, onFlip, flipped , disabled}) => {
  return (
    <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={flipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
      <FrontComponent onClick={onFlip} disabled={disabled} />
      <BackComponent text={text} value={value} />
    </ReactCardFlip>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect. All it does is flip the cards at random, which was why I decided to handle the event and the state in the child component. I'm starting to suspect that it has something to do with the ReactFlipCard library I'm using.